# Updated system - vim starts remembering cursor positions - get rid of that

Tags: vim

In Debian 8, vim was opening files as I expected it, placing the cursor in the first column of the first line. Now in Debian 9, probably a newer vim version, it "remembers" the last cursor position of a file name. This is extremely annoying in `git commit`, because it places the cursor somewhere down in the comments, even though the commit message file has no relation whatsoever to the previously opened commit message file.

How can I disable this "feature", making vim put the cursor in the beginning of the file when I open it?

---

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Feb 13 2017 00:56:16)
Included patches: 1-197, 322
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        -toolbar
-clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        -perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            -ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xpm
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you are looking for is `'viminfofile'`. Set it to `NONE` when you want to disable this feature, e.g.:

```
set viminfofile=NONE
```

Or set it for specific files:

```
autocmd BufReadPost COMMIT_EDITMSG setlocal viminfofile=NONE
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I set this just for files named `COMMIT_EDITMSG`?

Comment: @0__: something like the following in `.vimrc`: `autocmd BufReadPost COMMIT_EDITMSG setlocal noviminfo`.

Comment: got "E474: Invalid argument: noviminfo" with that, but `set viminfofile=NONE` did worked (found here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329545/disable-viminfo-completely )

Comment: @leberknecht: thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a `BufReadPost` autocmd that is being defined by the system vimrc. Check by doing `:verbose autocmd BufReadPost *` and look for a line similar to this:

```
if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") |   exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
```

The line immediately following it should tell you which startup file defined it.

If it is the system vimrc, and if you have your own `~/.vimrc` this should not be happening unless yours is explicitly sourcing the system vimrc.

Comment: Thanks, it says "Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim"

Comment: Again, that file should not be automatically loaded if you have a `~/.vimrc`. Do you have one? If so, is it explicitly loading a system vimrc?

Comment: No, I don't have that file. But I don't want to lose otherwise useful defaults. So how would I create `~/.vimrc` so that it loads the defaults and then just overrides `noviminfo` for a given file name (`COMMIT_EDITMSG`)?

Comment: You don't want to override noviminfo (I would argue the other answer to your question is incorrect). I would just copy the parts of defaults.vim that you want into your `~/.vimrc`, excluding those you don't. Eventually you probably want your own vimrc anyway, so better now than later.